# Solr count on facets

Tags: solr

I've searched for this, but still can't find a clear guide, so forgive me if I'm using the wrong terms. I have a Solr core that has Documents in the following format shown in JSON below. I can't figure out how to produce two query URLs:

Query 1: The total number of Docs. in the core (should equal 2 below)
Query 2: The total number of part numbers, across the whole core (should equal 7 below.

I appreciate any help!

```
"docs": [
  {
    "id": "4448fa65-1162-467c-b556-86ca18918cf0",
    "name": "My doc #1",
    "part numbers": [
      "12345",
      "54321",
      "98765",
      "56789"
    ],
    "_version_": 1486572809038594000
  },
  {
    "id": "d7cf0792-5b4a-4dca-9a28-9153bb1468ec",
    "name": "My doc #2",
    "part numbers": [
      "11111",
      "22222",
      "33333"
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

A query `*:*` will match all documents in the index. You can fire such a query and then look at the number of matches returned.

To get the total number of unique values for a field, you can search for `*:*` and then facet by the field with `facet.limit` set to `-1`. This will return all possible values of the field which can then be counted. Note that this method will be very inefficient if there are too many values and won't work at all if the field values are tokenized during indexing.

Answer (score 0):

```
http://<host_name>:<port>/solr/<core_name>/select?q=*:*&wt=json&indent=true&facet=true&facet.field=part_numbers&facet.mincount=1
```

Use above query which will give u 2 result set and facet results of part number (unique part numbers with there occurrences in the core). You can manipulate the facet result by the programming language that you are using